# When is a this stochastic integral a Martingale, stopping time in the integral.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

There are lots of questions on this site asking when Stochastic Integrals are Martingales. I have a similar question : Fix $0<T<\infty$. Given a Brownian Motion $W_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$, let $\tau$ be a stopping time with respect to the filtration generated by $\{W_t , t\in [0,T]\}$.

For what $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is

$$ \int_0^{t\wedge \tau} \sigma_s dW_s $$

a Martingale ?

Question 2 : or a Local Martingale?

I am not so interested in Question 2, but it would be nice to know.

EDIT : From what I have read I know some sort of measurability assumptions on $\sigma$ is required, in addition  I guess that something like 
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[\int_0^{t\wedge \tau} \|\sigma_s \|^2 ds \Big]< \infty$$
might be enough? Could anyone please please clarify :). Where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean matrix norm.

Comment: The integral which you wrote down is just a random variable. For martingales we need a stochastic process, e.g. it would make sense to ask under which assumptions $M_t = \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} \sigma \, dW_s$ is a (local) martingale.

Comment: Ahh this is exactly what I am interested in, you are right.